# RESTful URLs: "Impractical" Requests, and Requiring One of Two Request Parameters

Tags: spring, url, rest, spring-mvc

I have a RESTful URL that requires either the `offset` or the `prefix` request parameter (but not both).

```
GET /users?offset=0&count=20
GET /users?prefix=J&count=20
```

What's the best way to enforce this rule? Spring has the @RequestParam annotation with the 'required' property for optional parameters, but I want to enforce an "either-or" rule on these two parameters. I know I could do it in the code, but is there another way to do it?

Also, what's the proper way to handle "impractical" requests? Say I have 100 million users; the following request, although properly RESTful, is not something I want to support:

```
GET /users <-- Gets all 100 million users, crashes server and browser!
```

What should I send back?

Comment: What has this got to do with REST? These URLs are anything but REST-ful.

Comment: If this URL will result in the same view returned without dependence on session or cookies or the previous browsing history of a client, then it will be what you call RESTful. The offset, count, and prefix query parameters just give slices of the user view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two methods and choose one of them with `@RequestMapping`'s `params` attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(..., params = {"prefix", "!offset"})
public String usersWithPrefix(@RequestParam("prefix") ...) { ... }

@RequestMapping(..., params = {"offset", "!prefix"})
public String usersWithOffset(@RequestParam("offset") ...) { ... }
```

Comment: Cool! Can you take a look at my question about how to support "impractical" requests?

Comment: @RESTful: Look, for example, like it's done here, on Stackoverflow: request without parameters simply returns the first page.

Answer (score 0):

- what's the proper way to handle "impractical" requests?

The lesser-practiced principles of REST include the requirement that resources be "discoverable".  If you are asked for a complete list of 800 million users and you don't want to provide it, you might instead consider serving a page that describes in some way how to filter the collection: for example, an XForms document or HTML containing a FORM element with fields for offset/prefix/count, or a URI template with the appropriate parameters

Or you could just send a "413 Entity too large" error - **edit: no you can't.  Sorry, I misread the description of whath this code is for**

If you decide to go down the route of just sending the first page, I think I would send it as an HTTP redirect to /users?offset=0&count=20 so that the client has a better idea they've not got the full collection (and if your response contains a link to access subsequent pages, even better)